# Error Uncaught soapfault exception

Tags: php, webservice

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar un WS pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cotizaciones\cotizaciones.php on line 25

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cotizaciones\cotizaciones.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cotizaciones\cotizaciones.php(25): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://cotizac...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cotizaciones\cotizaciones.php on line 25
```

Me gustaría saber como podría solucionar este error, cabe aclarar que estoy usando la versión 5.2 de PHP, y el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$url = "https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl";
$context = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer'      => FALSE,
    'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
    'crypto_method'    => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
    )
);

$options = array(
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($context)
);

$params = array(
    'Entrada' => array(
        'Moneda'     => array ('item' => 0),
        'FechaDesde' => '2022-03-01',
        'FechaHasta' => '2022-03-01',
        'Grupo'      => 0
    )
);

$client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
$response = $client->Execute($params);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Agradezco si me pudieran ayudar. Desde ya gracias!

Comment: visto el wsdl, te indico que la parte de la definición de la entidad es un "sequence". por lo que es muy probable que la entidad `Entrada` que defines en tu array deba tener el mismo orden. Prueba a poner el orden de "Moneda, FechaDesde, FechaHasta, Grupo"

Comment: Ya probé con cambiar eso, y sigo con exactamente el mismo error